# How to save forum from personal vendetta

Tags: support, moderators

I have faced issue of my question being targeted by some high reputation users who instead of realizing their mistake and amending it made it a prestige issue.

reference question is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497378/sms-based-application-using-long-code

Comment: Sathya is a mod on SU. If he says your post is OT for SU, you should take the advice instead of thinking of it as vendetta.

Comment: "their mistake" Sorry, who do you think you are?

Comment: @BoltClock I am nobody... so does it mean I have no right to raise voice?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion if possible please gothough the reference attached before it is deleted.

Comment: No, but don't expect to be taken seriously if you're not interested in discussing this constructively.

Comment: @BoltClock did you go through the reference link, before understanding the issue? Anyway there are some good and helpful moderators also, I got help at chat from them and I have no time for this game. Bless you.

Comment: I saw the reference attached, it is off-topic for [so]. Also, a discussion is fruitful only if it's constructive, instead of being accusatory.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have no intention to do so given your attitude. Like I said, don't expect to be taken seriously. That's all I have to say to you.

Comment: For the record, in my observation Sathya has always been polite and professional in dealing with users on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I've never seen any evidence of a personal vendetta against anyone at any point. In fact, I supported him as a moderator candidate for Stack Overflow a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/election/4#post-15082173 and still would today.

Answer (score 20):

I don't have any vendetta against you or anyone else for that matter.

Let's have a look at your question:

> I have to develop SMS based application. In which, sms sent as cost ItemName will return the cost of the item from database. I have to setup entire system from procuring the number to setting up computer to receive the sms, running query over database and returning the cost to the number that enquired the cost with relevant information.

OK. This is setting up the question. Here are your actual questions:

> Also, can we use regular cell number as long code? If yes then which peripheral do we need to use with computer to use the simcard? Is there any cloud solution for it?

None of these are actual programming questions. What the heck does "any cloud solution" mean? You are asking for

- *how to setup a system which reviews SMS, runs a query & fetches the cost etc*. You can write entire books on this.
- *can we use regular cell number as long code?* What does 'long code' mean and how does it relate to programming?
- *then which peripheral do we need to use with computer to use the simcard* Again, nothing to do with programming and borderline shopping recommendation.

All of these are off-topic for Stack Overflow and Super User. The boilerplate

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

you see is when we select a question has offtopic for Stack Overflow. Notice that it says you *may* get help, not *will* get help.

To reiterate what I have mentioned in comments on the question:

- I have no vendetta(what will I have vendetta on?)
- I've linked you to the on-topic guidelines, asked you to edit the question. Merely adding 'I will do it in PHP' doesn't automagically make it a programming question.

Comment: You took the time to answer OP here? Admit it, you have a motive ;)

Comment: @BoltClock Holiday spirit 'n all :)

Comment: Many of the same points I brought up with the OP on chat. I really wish SO users thought a little before they migrated.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek just for the record, there was no migration, OP re/crossposted